# Comparing smoothing splines vs loess for smoothing?

Tags: regression, splines, loess

I wish to better understand the pros/cons for using either loess or a smoothing splines for smoothing some curve.

Another variation of my question is if there is a way to construct a smoothing spline in a way that will yield the same results as using loess.

Any reference or insight are welcomed.

Comment: Tal, The following well-cited article looks at many non-parametric regression approaches Buja, A., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (1989). [Linear Smoothers and Additive Models](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347115). *The Annals of Statistics*, 17(2), 453–510, best.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is some R code/example that will let you compare the fits for a loess fit and a spline fit:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
library(splines)

tmpfun <- function(x,y,span=.75,df=3) {
    plot(x,y)
    fit1 <- lm(y ~ ns(x,df))
    xx <- seq( min(x), max(x), length.out=250 )
    yy <- predict(fit1, data.frame(x=xx))
    lines(xx,yy, col='blue')
    fit2 <- loess(y~x, span=span)
    yy <- predict(fit2, data.frame(x=xx))
    lines(xx,yy, col='green')
    invisible(NULL)
}

tmplst <- list( 
    span=list('slider', from=0.1, to=1.5, resolution=0.05, init=0.75),
    df=list('slider', from=3, to=25, resolution=1, init=3))

tkexamp( tmpfun(ethanol$E, ethanol$NOx), tmplst )
```

You can try it with your data and change the code to try other types or options.  You may also want to look at the `loess.demo` function in the TeachingDemos package for a better understanding of what the loess algorythm does.  Note that what you see from loess is often a combination of loess with a second interpolation smoothing (sometimes itself a spline), the `loess.demo` function actually shows both the smoothed and the raw loess fit.

Theoretically you can always find a spline that approximates another continuous function as close as you want, but it is unlikely that there will be a simple choice of knots that will reliably give a close approximation to a loess fit for any data set.

Comment: Hi Greg:  1) Thank you for the answer.  2) I love your loess.demo function...

Answer (score 38):

The actual results from a smoothing spline or loess are going to be pretty similar.  They might look a little different at the edges of the support, but as long as you make sure it's a "natural" smoothing spline they will look really similar.

If you are just using one to add a "smoother" to a scatterplot, there's no real reason to prefer one over the other.  If instead you want to make predictions on new data, it's generally much easier to use a smoothing spline.  This is because the smoothing spline is a direct basis expansion of the original data; if you used 100 knots to make it that means you created ~100 new variables from the original variable.  Loess instead just estimates the response at all the values experienced (or a stratified subset for large data).

In general, there are established algorithms to optimize the penalty value for smoothing splines (mgcv in R probably does this the best).  Loess isn't quite as clear cut, but you'll generally still get reasonable output from any implementation.  MGCV also gives you a feel for equivalent Degrees of Freedom so you can get a feel for how "non-linear" your data is.

I find that when modeling on very large data, a simpler natural spline often provides similar results for minimal calculation compared to either a smoothing spline or loess.

Comment: +1, nice answer!  I like the clear theoretical exposition.

Comment: Why do they differ near the edges of the support though?

Comment: @imu96 AFAIK, non-parametric regression methods fall down at either end because they rely on a neighborhood of data to either side of the point along the $x$ axis being estimated, and towards the edges there is data on only one side, so the CIs get super wide, and the estimates get a tad biased. Each method suffers in this regard in a different manner because of different weights, different ways of defining neighborhood of data, etc.